# How to tell real and virtual keypresses apart?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an C# application which monitors keyboard and mouse events and reacts if a preset combination of key or mouse button presses occur.
The hotkey detection is already working by using keyboard and mouse hooks. However I run into trouble when the application's answer is sending a new key combo with SendInput().

Let's say the app waits for "*Alt+RMB*"m suppresses it and sends "*Shift+A*" instead. When I start to physically press "*Alt+RMB*" the combo is detected and a virtual "*Shift+A*" is sent.

However that fake keypress instantly mixes with the original keys so the app now detects the "*Alt+Shift+A+RMB*" combination which is not "*Alt+RMB*" anymore so "*Shift+A*" is stopped being sent. After the virtual keypress clears the system my real hotkey press is detected again and the cycle starts over. (Setups where "*A*" needs to be replaced by "*B*" while "*B*" with "*A*" would lead to an infinite loop.)

So it seems that my main problem is telling apart real and virtual key/mouse events. Any suggestions?

(Yes, the task is indeed similar to what [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) does. However I have custom business logic between the hotkey detection and the optional virtual input sending steps. Using [Autohotkey.dll](http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey/files/AutoHotkey-dll-txt.html) might be an option but I'm wary of the performance impact of a custom script interpreter running in there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the proper term for virtual key/mouse events is "**injected**" and the low level keyboard hook does provide a related flag in the [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Now I modified the hook related event management so it lets through any events with the "LLKHF_INJECTED" flag, without suppressing or informing the main logic about it.